# ReactJS - Get information back to main route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my `index.js`:

```
var routes = require('./config/routes');
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here are my routes :

```
var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeComponent}/>
      <Route path='create' component={CreateComponent} />
      <Route path='signUp' component={SignUpComponent} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

And finally my main container(`Main.js`) :

```
var Main = React.createClass({    
  render: function () {      
    return (    
      <div> 
       <NavBarComponent />
       <SecondComponent />
       {this.props.children}
       <FooterComponent/>
      </div>
    )   
  }   
});
```

As you may see, there are 3 common components for all pages (HeaderComponent, SecondComponent and FooterComponent). I would like, when a specific route changes (say for instance 'signUp' route), to hide SecondComponent.

FYI, here is my react configuration :

```
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-router": "^3.0.0"
```

Comment: Put a conditional statement in `Main` that looks at `window.location.href`. And only render `SecondComponent` if the conditional passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which route you're on by using browserHistory from react-router: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

and then test the route against a string.